# Validar registro de un profesor en un curso y una seccion PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una consulta que me esta dando un poco de dolores de cabeza. Estoy realizando un sistema donde registro cursos (violín, guitarra, flauta..) y cada curso tendrá una sección (sección A, sección B, sección C...). Cada curso tendrá un día y un horario por turnos relacionados de acuerdo a la sección (si es sección A sera solo lunes y miércoles de 8am a 12pm..si es sección B sera martes y jueves de 3pm a 5pm, y así..).

El problema viene al momento de registrar un profesor en una sección y un curso, una vez que yo registro al profesor, yo a través de un `combobox` lo puedo seleccionar luego de haber llenado la información de la sección con sus horas y días, mi pregunta es **¿como puedo evitar que un profesor que ya esta en un curso de 8am a 12pm solo los lunes y miércoles no pueda ser registrado nuevamente por ejemplo en una sección C donde son los martes y miércoles a la misma hora que la seccion A?** quiero evitar es el choque de horas por profesor al registrarlo en una sección y curso.

Un profesor puede dar muchos cursos, pero no en el mismo turno (matutino-vespertino) el mismo día. Pero si puede dar un curso en el turno matutino y otro en el turno vespertino.

Por ahora tengo mi BD de esta manera:

```
CREATE TABLE `seccion` (
  `id_seccion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `horaEntrada` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `horaSalida` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dias` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cupos` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `curso_id_curso` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `personas_cedula` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `turno` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

y trate de hacer lo siguiente, pero como dije, me da dolores de cabeza ya como colocar esto que consulto:

```
$result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(personas_cedula) FROM seccion WHERE personas_cedula='$cbx_profesor' AND turno='matutino' AND dias='$dias' AND horaEntrada='$horaEntrada'  ");
                    $row = @mysqli_fetch_row($result1);
                    if($row[0]>=1){


                        $errors[] = "El profesor ya se encuentra registrado en un curso";

                    } else {





                    $sql = "INSERT INTO seccion (descripcion, horaEntrada, horaSalida, dias,cupos,curso_id_curso,personas_cedula,turno) VALUES('$descripcion','$horaEntrada','$horaSalida','$dias','$cupos','$cbx_curso','$cbx_profesor','$turno')";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

a quien pueda ayudarme, se lo agradeceria mucho de antemano!

Comment: ¿Has pensado en la opción de hacer una tabla intermedia que te ayude a crear las "colisiones" de manera que solamente la tengas que consultar para saber que "secciones" no pueden ir juntas?

Comment: ¿Quieres implementarlo en forma de trigger en el lado del servidor MySQL o por estructuras de control en el lado de PHP?

Comment: @Sakrow no comprendi muy bien tu comentario